# CKEditor displaying multiple cursors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Is that possible to display multiple cursors in one editor,

because we want to implement the collaborative editor,

we need to show more than 1 cursor that let the other users know - 
which part is editing and the edit process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor uses the native cursor, but you don't need a real cursor because that's where the current user is typing. Instead you want to show where other users are typing, so you just want to show a custom marker and move it around as the other user changes the document.

Comment: thanks for answering, so you suggest that use custom tag like "editor.insertHtml" to show the other typing? how about we will mix the diff_match_patch libs to do the work? any suggestion? thanks!

Comment: What "diff_match_patch libs" are you talking about? you asked how to add multiple cursors in CKEditor and I've replied that CKEditor uses the native one and you'll have to handle anything extra yourself. If you have other questions, please create a new question showing your code and the exact problem that you have.

Comment: sorry about that deriving so much problem, and thanks for your suggestion.